# Use Multiple ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter Spring security based on endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I want to authorize my two sets of endpoint

1. provider url with pattern (`/provider/api/**`)
2. customer url with pattern (`/customer/api/**`)

All other endpoints can be ignored.
I am using AWS Cognito as my authorization server and have built two different User Pools for `Provider` and `Customer`. I have set up the Spring Boot Security from guide https://medium.com/@arjunsk/resource-server-with-cognito-b7fbfbee0155

Here are my two Security Configuration

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class CustomerResourceServerSecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private final ResourceServerProperties resource;

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // Very important
    http.cors();

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.requestMatchers()
          .antMatchers("/customer/api/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/customer/api/**").authenticated();
  }

  // Enabling Cognito Converter
  @Bean
  public TokenStore jwkTokenStore() {
    return new JwkTokenStore(
        Collections.singletonList(resource.getJwk().getKeySetUri()),
        new CognitoAccessTokenConverter(),
        null);
  }
}
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ProviderResourceServerSecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Qualifier("providerResourceServerProperties")
  private final ResourceServerProperties resource;

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // Very important
    http.cors();

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.requestMatchers()
          .antMatchers("/provider/api/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/provider/api/**").authenticated();
  }

  // Enabling Cognito Converter
  @Bean
  public TokenStore jwkTokenStore() {
    return new JwkTokenStore(
        Collections.singletonList(resource.getJwk().getKeySetUri()),
        new CognitoAccessTokenConverter(),
        null);
  }
}
```

My Different Configuration is determined by Configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerPropertiesConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties("security.customer.oauth2.resource")
  public ResourceServerProperties customerResourceServerProperties() {
    return new ResourceServerProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("security.provider.oauth2.resource")
  public ResourceServerProperties providerResourceServerProperties() {
    return new ResourceServerProperties();
  }
}
```

*If I use a single configuration, it works properly. But if use both configuration, I see that my provider configuration is always ignored and all provider endpoint is authorized by the customer security configuration. I tried setting up the Order but was not able to resolve it.*

**Please help in setting up two different configurations based on an endpoint such that provider URL is authenticated by only `ProviderResourceServerSecurityConfiguration` and customer URL is authenticated only by `CustomerResourceServerSecurityConfiguration`.**